# Quantifiying the similarity between two sentences

Tags: r, string, topic-modeling, sentence-similarity

For a project I want to quantify the similarity between two strings of text. The strings are titles of research proposals, and within researchers we want to calculate the similarity between pairs of them. The dataframe currently exists of three columns: (a) the researcher id, (b) a project title, (c) a project title. I have hundreds of rows (researchers).

Let's imagine we have two project titles within a researcher:

> "How cardioviscular diseases can be solved by looking at DNA."
>
> "Genes and the high cardioviscular disease risk for old men."

Ideally, a measure of similarity would not only pick up the exact words ("cardioviscular" and "disease"), but also connect "DNA" to "Genes". Moreover, all words that are not substantial ("how", "can", "be", "at", etc) should be removed.

I have no experience with these issues. How would I be able to quantify the similarity between these two string variables for a large number of researchers? In the ideal scenario I would program this in R.

Comment: As a first step, you could use the tidytext package to create a data frame, remove what are called stopwords and thereby isolate the substantive words in each title.  You might then create your own synonym list (related words like DNA = genes).  At the moment I'm at a loss how to find similar titles, however.

Comment: If you need to check similarity, google cosine similarity or edit distance.

Comment: This isn't a specific programming question and therefore doesn't really belong on Stack Overflow since you don't actually know exactly what to tell the computer to do. For more general data analysis advice, maybe try [datascience.se] or search for "natural language processing"?